# Load balancer requirements

Tags: load-balancing

I have got two dedicated servers with apache installed as their webserver. How can I implement load balancing on my servers in a way that if a a server is out of service or has a problem the other one is replaced?

Is there any hardware or software requirement? Should I ask my server administrator to do something?

Comment: [One could write a book on this subject](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-Load-Balancing-Performance-Networking/dp/1430236809), so to me it's too broad a question.  That said, [here's one possible solution](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) you could be thinking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions

1)Software Loadbalancer(HAProxy)(free)

2)Hardware Loadbalancer(F5,Brocade,A10)(not free)

Decide between these two according to our budget and needs and configure accordingly .